# Converting Vector to ByteString in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am puzzled on how I can convert a vector of Data.Vector.Storable to a ByteString. I am guessing I am missing something fairly obvious.

I need to convert it to ByteString because I want to send it over the network, using Network.Socket.ByteString, and it seems to be the most efficient data structure to do so.

How can I write code to write the function

```
writeToByteString :: Vector Int -> ByteString
writeToByteString v =
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Well, a `ByteString` is composed of `Word8`s, how do you want to convert `Int` to `Word8`?  Since `Int` is platform specific, this is really the tricky bit.  After that it can be as simple as `BS.pack . V.toList` (although that might not be the most efficient way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you actually want to achieve. As bheklilr mentioned, `Int` representation is platform specific.

But under the hood, a storable vector is a piece of memory. To get its content, use `unsafeToForeignPtr0`. Here is an example:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable as V
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS

import Foreign

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let v = V.generate 10 id :: V.Vector Int
      (fptr, len) = V.unsafeToForeignPtr0 v
  print v
  bs <- withForeignPtr fptr $ \ptr ->
    BS.packCStringLen (castPtr ptr, len * sizeOf (undefined :: Int))
  print $ BS.unpack bs
```

Output:

```
fromList [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this is exactly what I wanted. I used Int as an example but it could need to support several C-based types.